If $N$ contains a maximal submodule, does this imply that $ \text{Rad} N $ is a superfluous submodule of $N$?
If $M$ is a finitely generated module over a ring $R$ with unity, it can be readily demonstrated that the radical of $M$, denoted $ \text{Rad} M$, qualifies as a superfluous submodule of $M$.
The foundation of the proof rests on a critical property of finitely generated modules: Since $M$ is finitely generated, any proper submodule of $M$ is necessarily contained within a maximal submodule of $M$.
This observation prompts several pertinent inquiries:

If $N$ encompasses a maximal submodule, does this imply that $ \text{Rad} N $ is a superfluous submodule of $N$?
Given that any non-zero projective module contains a maximal submodule, is the radical of a non-zero projective module also superfluous? How does this extend to free modules?

For further reading on these concepts, consider the following resources:

Radical of a module
Superfluous submodule


I disagree with the votes that this "needs more focus."  The first two questions are tightly related and well motivated by the first paragraph. The third question, well, isn't really necessary.  In fact there is a single answer to all three.

Thank you for highlighting the deficiencies in the question I posed.

i'm also suggesting a newer, more specific, title.

I am still contemplating a more appropriate title. Might you have any insightful suggestions?

I already changed it.

Thanks so much.

This question has an answer in mathoverflow. You will find a demonstration of a free module with non-superfluous Jacobson radical.
The example given there is of a free module $F$ of countable rank over a discrete valuation domain. It describes a proper submodule $T$ of $F$ such that $T+JF=F$, where $JF$ is the Jacobson radical of $F$.
Incidentally, I thought quite a bit about this sort of thing when investigating semi-Artinian and semi-Noetherian modules.  For a module, having an essential socle is equivalent to each submodule containing a minimal submodule.  But the dual proposition "superfluous radical iff every quotient has a maximal submodule" does not hold: the $p$ adic integers used in the example above is a semi-Noetherian module over itself, and an arbitrary sum of semi-Noetherian modules remains semi-Noetherian. So the example produced is semi-Noetherian (having maximal submodules for each nonzero submodule) and yet its radical is not superfluous.
